# AVPlayer not always seeking correctly

Tags: ios, swift, avkit

I've got a player setup with a seek method that looks like this:

```
let time = CMTime(seconds: seconds, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))
player.seek(to: time, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)
```

Then each frame update with a display link I check if any new frame is available like this:

```
let currentTime = player!.currentItem!.currentTime()

if playerItemVideoOutput.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: currentTime) {
    if let pixelBuffer = playerItemVideoOutput.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: currentTime, itemTimeForDisplay: nil) {
        update(pixelBuffer)
    }
}
```

Tho `.hasNewPixelBuffer` dose not always return something even if I've seeked...

It works fine when panning in my video app, missing a couple frames here and there is not visible, tho when resetting the playhead to zero, with a seek to zero seconds, sometimes fails...

Any idea what I'm missing or what could be wrong?

Comment: did you tried with `toleranceAfter: kCMTimePositiveInfinity` instant `toleranceAfter: .zero` ?

Comment: @NazmulHasan I just tried it, and it kinda works, tho only once every second.

Comment: so what are you looking for?

Comment: accuracy of 16ms and for the seek to be in sync with hasNewPixelBuffer

Comment: tho I'm not really sure what toleranceBefore and toleranceAfter is referring to

Comment: I think I might have had a fps missmatch...

Comment: Yes! pretty much sure. may be fps missmatch